# AppleScript: Toggle Between Safari Windows?

Tags: applescript

If I have two safari windows open, just one tab in each, how do I get applescript to switch to either of the windows at will? Or in other words, toggle between them.

I tried, `activate window 1` (or, the first window), and `activate window 2` (or the second window), only ever activates the first window.

I tried `open window 1` etc, open doesn't exist.

I tried using the system events, `click menu bar 1 option`, thinking maybe menu bar 2 was for window 2, didn't work.

I tried making `do javascript` on a specific tab show that page, couldn't get that to work.

Ultimately I did figure out I could use a keyboard shortcut, but I wanted to see if there was a more 'vanilla' applescript way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I do just this

```
tell application "Safari"
  set index of window 2 to 1
end tell
```

The new window that shows up is frozen. I fixed this by doing this

```
    tell application "Safari"
    set theWindows to windows
    set win2 to item 2 of theWindows
    tell win2
        set visible to false
        set visible to true
        set index to 1
    end tell
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

- If the windows are not full screen (in different spaces) just change the `index` of the window

  ```
    tell application "Safari"
        set index of window 2 to 1
    end tell
  ```
- If the windows are in different spaces you have to switch the spaces by executing the keystrokes with `System Events`. The default values on the US keyboard are ⌃←

  ```
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 123 using (control down)
    end tell
  ```

  and ⌃→

  ```
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 124 using (control down)
    end tell
  ```

Comment: Hey @vadian, I noticed that after running the set index command, the window that pops up is frozen, until I manually click inside of it. Got a fix for that? I again tried activate window 1 and window 2, and also just plain activate, and it still stays frozen until I click inside of it.